# I want to add 2 letters of the words where I have picked from a ComboBox to a Label

Tags: java

I want to add 2 letters of the words where I have picked from a ComboBox to a Label. As an example there is a list of subjects if a combo box like "Science", "Maths" ect so I want only first two letter added to the Lable Science = "sc"

[image]

As like the picture I need to add first letter to that Label "Add".

here is the code

```
public addteacher1() {
    initComponents();
    kk.addItem("Maths");
    kk.addItem("Science");
    kk.addItem("English");
    kk.addItem("Sinhala");
    kk.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == kk){
            if(kk.getSelectedItem().equals("Maths")){
                String s =  kk.getSelectedItem().toString();
                for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {
                    char g  = s.charAt(i);
                    jLabel9.setText(arr);
                    //char c = reader.nextChar();
                }
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Without code, how can we help? We're good, but not that good.

Comment: Please be precise in your questions. If you want only the two first characters of a String, you can use yourString.substring(0, 2);

Comment: If you want the 2 first characters you can use substring, but your code is needed to know what is the issue

Comment: I have put the code :) thank you

Comment: And i need to send them to the "Add" lable where i have shown in the picture. when i select from some item from the combo box

Comment: I have formatted the code. Understand what `setText(...)` is doing each time the loop runs. Create your String in the loop, then after this is done, set the text. Or use `subString(...)`.

Comment: You can use s.substring(0, 2) to get the frist two characters

Comment: is there a way to add those two sub strings to created lable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your string is

```
String science = "Science"
```

you can use

```
science.charAt(0)+science.charAt(1)
```

OR

```
science.substring(0,2)
```